# Where are kubelet logs in AKS stored?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I would like to view kubelet logs going back in time in Azure AKS. All I could find from Azure docs was how to ssh into the nodes and list the logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubelet-logs) but I feel like this has to be aggregated in Log Analytics somewhere right ?

However I wasn't able to find anything in Log Analytics for Kubernetes. Am I missing something ?

We have omsagent daemonset installed and Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces is enabled

Thanks :)

Comment: does this help you ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-livedata-overview

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can get the kubernetes events of nodes that way, but I cannot see any option to get kubelet logs.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce this issue in my environment and got below results:***

I created resource group and VM by setting up the Subscription

```
az account set --subscription "subscription_name"
az group create --location westus resourcegroup_name
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/WaF4Ujl.png]

- created the AKS Cluster with the parameter to enable the **AKS Container Insights**
- The following Example will creates the Cluster with name **AKSRG**.

`az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n resourceGroup_name --enable-managed-identity --node-count 1 --enable-addons monitoring --enable-msi-auth-for-monitoring  --generate-ssh-keys`

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wesUd9I.png]

- Here I have configured the **kubectl** to connect the kubernetes cluster with the **get-credentials** command

[image: https://i.imgur.com/eNv0sjI.png]

I have created the interactive shell connection to the node
using **kubectl debug**

```
kubectl debug node/pod_name -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2wQSzIs.png]
I have used the below Command in after hash(#) tag

```
journalctl -u kubelet -o cat
```

To get the logs check the nodes and pods

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nU65SNF.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xdlHson.png]

We can use the below command to check the **KUBE LOGS**

```
kubectl logs pod_name
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nH7mt7y.png]

**Reference:**

[View kubelet logs in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubelet-logs)

Comment: You tried to reproduce the issue. Did you succeed to reproduce? Did you solve the problem? Do you consider this an answer according to [answer]?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My question was asking if there are aggregated logs somewhere in Azure where I could view kubelot logs going back in time. This shows only how to check for kubelet logs locally.

I've reached out to Microsoft support and they informed me that they do not collect kubelet logs out of the box, so that answers the question :)